# Newlines and their effect in String concatenation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-concatenation

it is a bit that I work with JavaScript and while working i came across a very weird case that, with a bit of time, I have fixed in my project, but that I could also replicate.

The issue is regarding the parsing of strings on multiple lines, through concatenation.

My test case is the following:

```
> var a = "s1"
undefined
> var b = "s2"
undefined
> a + b
's1s2'
> a+
... +b
's1NaN'
> a++b
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

(where the second is basically a single command, a++b, with a newline between a+ and +b).

Shouldn't the second test case behave exactly as the third one?
This happens both in Chrome 39 and Firefox 34.

Is this behavior following the standard? Am I missing something so obvious that I'm not thinking about?

Comment: The second case is the same as `a+ +b`(≠`a++b`). This is standard behaviour. You should really use semicolons.

Comment: I do generally, and I totally agree. That line in my project was my only exception, since it was a very long string concatenation, which I happened to do on two lines. :)

Comment: But for that you'll need to use a single `+` only. Regardless on which line you place it.

Comment: I know. That was indeed a coding mistake that I did, which showed me this behavior with the new lines and the separation of the operators, which I did not know of. :) In my project, I indeed have  eliminate one of the two plus symbols.

Comment: I wonder what your question is then?

Comment: As I said, I did not know of the behavior in the answer given by "thefourtheye". I was wondering whether this behavior was standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a+
+b
```

is actually treated as

```
a + (+b)
```

Since `b` is not a number, the numeric value of `b` is given as `NaN`, by the unary + operator.

In the last case, `a++b`, it is evaluated as `(a++)b`. Since JavaScript is not expecting anything after `++` operator, it fails with the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: The thing is that I also didn't make use of the Unary plus until now (my background is a Java background). As reference for readers, I will leave the explanation of the unary plus here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

This, together with the fact that newlines are not ignored in JavaScript. :)